# Django2, the forms in template do not work

Tags: python, django, django-templates

(only in Django 2 & 2.0.1)
if I use `{{form}}` it works but if I use `{{form.field}}` it disappears all

```
    <form method="POST" class="post-form"  method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
    <input type="submit" id="salva" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class PreventivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preventivo
        fields = ['cliente','prestazione1', 'ripetizione1', 'prestazione2', 'ripetizione2', 'prestazione3', 'ripetizione3', 'prestazione4', 'ripetizione4', 'prestazione5', 'ripetizione5']
```

Comment: Please show the form.

Comment: What is your problem? If you want to display form, use 'form.as_p', 'form.as_ul'… And you wrote the method attribute twice while the action attribute is missing.

Comment: dosen't work it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: What did you actually try after following the docs on [rendering the fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)? `{{ form.field }}` isn't going to work because you don't have any fields name `field`. You need `{{ field.cliente }}`, `{{ field.prestazione1 }}` and so on.

Comment: Please add your views.py file.

Comment: @Alasdair   I used "field" as a generic field. if I use {{form.cliente}} ... it does not work

Comment: You still haven’t included enough information in your question to reproduce the problem, so we can’t help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use {{form}} then it gets all these value:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" autofocus maxlength="254" required id="id_username" /></td></tr>  
<tr><th><label for="id_password">Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="password" required id="id_password" /></td></tr>
```

But if you use {{form.username}} and {{form.password}} then:

```
<input type="text" name="username" autofocus maxlength="254" required id="id_username" />
<input type="password" name="password" required id="id_password" />
```

So you will only see the input field not label for that input field